# How to stop TCP server in Julia?

Tags: tcp, julia, tcplistener

TCP example

```
@async begin
  server = listen(2000)
    while true
    sock = accept(server)
    println("Hello World\n")
  end
end
```

To close the connection, you need to call the `close` method:

```
close(sock)
```

How to stop the listener?

```
close(server) #LoadError: accept: software caused connection abort (ECONNABORTED)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Doing a normal (not `@async`) example, both `close(sock)` and `close(server)` work fine (julia 0.6.0). And with your example above, I can't access server and sock to close them anyway

Comment: perhaps you meant to define the server and socket *outside* the `@async` task?

Comment: I get the error you described only if I try to close the server without having closed the socket first. (which is possible in the REPL if you take the `server = listen(2000)` outside the async block. And since you're printing your own string, rather than reading from the stream, the stream never closes.  Maybe you should try a better example?

Comment: also, note that that error isn't necessarily a bad thing. It's just there to be caught with a try block when the server closes unexpectedly, but you can totally just do "try close(server) catch" etc.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than keep commenting, here's what I think you were probably trying to do:

From the julia REPL:

```
julia> server = listen(2000)
Base.TCPServer(active)

julia> @async begin
         while true
           sock = accept(server)
           print(readstring(sock))
         end
       end
```

From another terminal:

```
~ $ nc localhost 2000
Hello from the other terminal
[Ctrl-D]   % i.e. signal end of file. this closes the connection
```

In the julia repl, you'll see "Hello from the other terminal" printed as soon as you send the EOF signal, but otherwise the julia prompt will continue as normal. If you repeat this process from the netcat terminal you'll see the message printed in the REPL again, because the socket keeps reactivating inside the while loop.

Ideally if you wanted to shut the whole thing down, you would first `close(sock)` and then `close(server)`. But, you can't close the socket directly, because it's in the "while" loop and it keeps getting reactivated, and you don't have direct access to the variable "sock".

Therefore you can only close the server, fully expecting an error. <s>So catch it in a try block instead</s>

EDIT: sorry, my bad, the exception relates to the socket, not the server, so you need to wrap *that* in a try catch block inside your async block instead:

```
@async begin
     while true
       try
         sock = accept(server)
         print(readstring(sock))
       catch ex
         print("exiting while loop")
         break
       end 
     end
   end
```

Comment: Just thought I'd note here that OP probably included the `listen` statement inside the `@async` because that's where it is in the example in the [docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/networking-and-streams/#A-simple-TCP-example-1). This answer did help me a lot, by the way, although it makes me feel a bit uncomfortable that we are deliberately causing an error in order to close the task.